# Get the name of the property from attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, web

I am using C# 4.5 and ASP.NET MVC 5.
I have the following:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Prop1 is required")]
public string Prop1 { get;set;}

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Prop2 is required")]
public string Prop2 { get;set;}
```

As you see the error message is the property name plus the " is required" string. What I need is instead of typing the property name and the message for every property, use a generic method composer, that will return the name of the decorated property and a string that I add, something like:

```
public string GetMessage()
{
    // Caller property should be a variable that is retrieved dynamically 
    // that holds the name of the property that called the function
    return CallerProperty + " is required";
}
```

so now I can user:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = GetMessage())]
public string Prop2 { get;set;}
```

so in brief: How can I know the property name that is decorated by an attribute.

Comment: That is not possible - attributes are metadata and must be known at compile tile. But all you need to is `ErrorMessage = "{0} is required"`

Comment: This is what  I want, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use reflection.

Pseudo

```
public List<Required> CallerProperty<T>(T source)
{
    List<Required> result = new List<Required>();
    Type targetInfo = target.GetType();
    var propertiesToLoop = source.GetProperties();
    foreach (PropertyInfo pi in propertiesToLoop)
    {
        Required possible = pi.GetCustomAttribute<Required>();
        if(possible != null)
        {
            result.Add(possible);
            string name = pi.Name; //This is the property name of the property that has a required attribute
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

This is just a demo of how to capture a custom attribute on a property. You have to work out how to manage a list of them, or whatever you need in order to generate the return type you need. Perhaps map it with the "pi.Name" also referenced? I don't know precisely what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "nameof" expression as follows:

```
class Class1
{
    [CustomAttr("prop Name: " + nameof(MyProperty))]
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }
}

public class CustomAttr : Attribute
{
    public CustomAttr(string test)
    {

    }
}
```